# why SOAP response comes with xml tags in iOS, and how to avoid it

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, soap

I'm working with SOAP web service.if I check web service in the browser the Response is

```
[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]
```

but when I check in the iOS the response comes with xml tags.like this

```
[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

this is my method....

```
NSString *autenticationkey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"authkey"];
    NSString *acode = @"YQM";
    //NSString *empty = @"";
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<GetAirport xmlns=\"http://mapi.uk/\">"
                             "<Authkey>%@</Authkey>"
                             "<AirportCode>%@</AirportCode>"
                             "</GetAirport>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>"
                             ,autenticationkey,acode];


    NSData *soapData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *mainurlName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somuturlop/GetAirport"];
    NSURL *getcodeserviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlName];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:getcodeserviceUrl];
    NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://mopi.uk" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"mpi.uk" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HOST"];
    [theRequest addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:soapData];




NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"data Task With Request error:%@", error);
            return;
        }
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

            if (statusCode != 200) {
                NSLog(@"data Task With Request HTTP status code :%ld", (long)statusCode);
                return;
            }
        }

        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [webData appendData:data];

        NSLog(@"Received bytes from the server :%lu", (unsigned long)[webData length]);
        resultString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData bytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

resultString gives this result. I want to get this json data into an Array.

I tried with this. but it didn't work

```
resultStringOne = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *jsonData = [resultStringOne dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray *getArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError]
```

Comment: Why do you think the browser is not getting the same tag?

Comment: Checkout [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) for xml parsing in objective. Also browser parser and objective parser handle the xml different with output different, as in objective c u get xml tag extra so that you could handle it well at ios end.

Comment: did you check the source-code of response in browser? the xml tag may be invisible in browser view.

Comment: I want to use this response data(want to put this data into an array)
how to do that

Comment: I don't know @Avi but results are different. and I want to use this data(json). how can I do that

Comment: You state the results are different, but offer no proof.  As @thst wrote, what does the source view in the browser display?

Comment: this is the source view
`
[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]`

Comment: no xml tags in the page source. other than that , did I do any wrong thigs here.@thst

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I removed xml tags from the string.now it works.....
used this method to remove xml tags.

```
- (NSString *)stringBystrippingxml:(NSString *)provideString
{
    NSRange range;
    while ((range = [provideString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        provideString = [provideString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

    return provideString;
}
```

then used return provideString, then .....

```
resultStringOne = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *one = [self stringBystrippingxml:resultStringOne];
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *jsonData = [one dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray *getArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

this works fine....... thnx all and thanx @m.kocikowski for the tag remove method.